# ion nav buttons are not in line on ion nav bar

Tags: css, ionic-framework

The buttons inside my ion-nav-bar are not in-line.

I have two buttons, on left and right. However, the right side button is off center.

My markup is:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left"><button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button></ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right"><button class="button button-icon ion-power" ng-click="onOffService()"></button></ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-view name="mainContent"></ion-nav-view> 
</ion-nav-bar>
```

No css changes have been made and here is what the bar looks like:
[image]

Comment: It seems to be aligned in this demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/009ec287362e Maybe it is being affected by something else.

Comment: I think height is changed

Comment: I have tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to be working :(

Answer (score 0):

`ion-nav-view` is supposed not to be included inside `ion-nav-bar`,

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBar/